# select collection -- displaying more than 1 column value in the select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got the following line of code in my new player.html.erb file.

```
<% form_for @player, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

Team: <%=  f.select(:SUB_TEAM, [["--New--", "new"]] + Team.all.collect {|p| [ p.BSR_TEAM_NAME, p.BSR_TEAM_ID  ] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :selected => params[:teamID].to_i}) %>


...
<% end %>
```

User can associate the player to a team.

Currently for the Team field, a drop down list is displayed with the team names.

Now i need to include the 'team leader name' next to the team name in the drop down list.

I tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
Team: <%=  f.select(:SUB_TEAM, [["--New--", "new"]] + Team.all.collect {|p| [ p.BSR_TEAM_NAME -- p.BSR_TEAM_LEADERNAME, p.BSR_TEAM_ID  ] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :selected => params[:teamID].to_i}) %>
```

I would be grateful if somebody could give me a hint how to display the team lead name next to the team name.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you just have a syntax error.  Should `p.BSR_TEAM_NAME -- p.BSR_TEAM_LEADERNAME` really be a string like `"#{p.BSR_TEAM_NAME} -- #{p.BSR_TEAM_LEADERNAME}"` ?

Comment: Were you getting a runtime error with your code above?

Comment: Using #{p.BSR_TEAM_NAME} -- #{p.BSR_TEAM_LEADERNAME} seems to have solved the problem..yes i was getting a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Team: <%=  f.select(:SUB_TEAM, [["--New--", "new"]] + Team.all.collect {|p| [ "#{p.BSR_TEAM_NAME} -- #{p.BSR_TEAM_LEADERNAME}", p.BSR_TEAM_ID  ] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :selected => params[:teamID].to_i}) %>
```